# C# ASP.NET: Show download prompt to user to allow user to download remote image file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

How to show user the download prompt (browser's default) pop-up box to allow the user to choose to Save or Open an image file?

The file is not in the same domain. I've the full URL of the image file.

`Response.TransmitFile` will not work with remote file download. Hence, this is not a duplicate question as suggested.

I am using C# and HTML, Javascript, JQuery.

Comment: `Response.TransmitFile` does not work in my case.

Comment: Hence @Daniel, this is not a "duplicate"

Comment: explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: `Response.TransmitFile` does not work with remote file download or a file with full URL which is not in the same domain (which is my case). It is only used for transmitting files in the same domain's sub folders accepting only relative path as parameter.

Comment: so basically you want to proxy the request to the other server forcing a download?